# Time to decrease water temperature by 5F from different initial temperatures

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, water

Is the time to (naturally) decrease temperature of water by 5 degrees the same, regardless of the initial temperature? Imagine 3 glasses of water (a, b c) in a room temperature of 70F.

There are 3 scenarios:

```
a) initial water temperature: 120F. final temperature: 115F
b) initial water temperature: 110F. final temperature: 105F
c) initial water temperature: 100F. final temperature: 95F
```

The question is - does the time for water to decrease its temperature by 5F for all cases above (a,b,c) is the same? Or the time is different for each case?

Comment: related:http://www.ugrad.math.ubc.ca/coursedoc/math100/notes/diffeqs/cool.html  Newton's Law of Cooling

Comment: So like ambient temperature is not factor?   -1

Comment: I guess the time would be the same then?

Comment: @Tom: no, the fact that the water is cooling means there is a colder body involved. Heat then flows from the hotter to the cooler object. The larger the temperature difference, the faster the cooling. See Newton's Law of cooling: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_law_of_cooling

Comment: I think I get it. So for 70F room temperature, the time to decrease water temperature for above scenarios is: a (fastest time) and c (slowest time)?

Comment: Sounds like you are assuming that the heat is leaking out of the water into an environment at some standard temperature. If so, you should probably state that in your question.

Comment: Yes, imagine three glasses of water (120F, 110F, 100F) in a steady room temperature (70F).

Comment: Please add this new information to your question; potential answerers shouldn't have to read all the comments to understand what your question means.

Comment: Added right after commented on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No, they will cool at different rates**

[Newton's law of cooling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_law_of_cooling) states that

$$
\frac{dQ}{dt} \propto T-T_{env}
$$
where $T$ is the temperature of the water and $T_{env}$ is the temperature of the environment. As you can see, the larger the temperature difference, the more quickly the water will lose heat. We can assume that the specific heat of water will not change much with temperature, and no phase changes occur. Therefore, hot water will decrease in temperature more quickly than warm water.